# Sequelize.js. How to find object in JSON datatype with iLike condition?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a table named `orders` having several fields, one of the field is having `jsonb` datatype. The name of this field is `customer_detail`. I am storing json object in this field. Now I want to perform search operation on this field, I want to search in orders table with customer name and email.

**Model:**

```
const Order = db.sequelize.define(
  'orders',
  {
     
    customer_detail: {
      type: db.Sequelize.JSONB
    },
     
  },
  {
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true
  }
);

module.exports = Order;
```

**Query:**

```
const orderData = await model.Order.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        customer_detail: {
            [Op.contains]: {
                name: 'search_term',
                email: 'search_term'
            }
        }
    },
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],
    limit: 50
});
```

Above query returns correct result but it matches whole word. So for example if the name of customer is John Doe and I search with only John then it does not return the result but if I search with John Doe then I get correct result.

I also tried below query but it failed.

```
const orderData = await model.Order.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        customer_detail: {
            [Op.contains]: {
                name: {
                    [Op.iLike]: '%search_term%'
                }
                email:  {
                    [Op.iLike]: '%search_term%'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],
    limit: 50
});
```

Comment: The requirement to do this, is a strong indication that you probably should think about a properly normalized data model.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `[Op.contains]` ? Are they keys 'name' and 'email' optional ? Does customer_detail sometimes values `{}`.

If yes maybe it is possible to separate the tests for the key presence and the test for the value ILIKE.

For example:

```js
const orderData = await model.Order.findAndCountAll({
    where: {
        // Do a "AND" to pile some checks
        [Op.and]: [
            // Check the presence of the "name" key
            sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('customer_detail->>\'$.name\''), true),
            // Check the presence of the "email" key
            sequelize.where(sequelize.literal('customer_detail->>\'$.email\''), true),
            // Check the values
            customer_detail: {
                name: {
                    [Op.iLike]: '%search_term%'
                },
                email: {
                    [Op.iLike]: '%search_term%'
                }
            }
        ],
    },
    order: [['id', 'DESC']],
    limit: 50
});
```